# Excel VBA Insert Single quote into column with 16+ Numeric Numbers

Tags: excel, vba, precision

In Column M of a sheet called 'FF' , I have a series of values that can be 16+ numerical digits (numbers in the trillions).  As a result, excel is losing precision and not properly displaying the values.

I have realized that if I manually put a single quote in the formula bar, it displays the number properly and saves the CSV properly as well.  Is there a way to do this for all of column M if Column M already has numeric values populated?

[image]

Conceptually, I was hoping to do something like this where the single quote doesn't actually appear

```
Sub SingleQuote()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FF")
        .Cells(2, 18).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(Stage!M2="""","""",='M2"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any format that you can apply to the column to get the desired values to display in the cells ??

Comment: If the values are already populated, then you've already lost some precision in your values.  You need to format as text before you add the values.

Comment: Excel's numeric precision is limited to 15 (?) digits - if your values have more digits than that then you *will* lose data unless you enter and store those values as text. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/#:~:text=The%20precision%20of%20a%20number,within%2015%20digits%20of%20precision.